# Apache: doing pattern matching and grouping with a RewriteRule leads to the local path instead of getting the URL component

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I've searched if this has been answered before with no joy.

I'd like to use `RewriteRule`'s pattern matching to get the path requested and redirect the client elsewhere keeping the path in the resulting redirect.

I thought something like this would do the trick:

```
RewriteRule.  ^(.*)$ http://testserver/test/$1
```

If the user requests `foo`, send him to `test/foo` (don't worry about looping, I put some `RewriteCond` logic to prevent that).

To my surprise, Apache ends up with something like    `http://testserver/foo/var/www/html`. What it did was the following:

```
/bar   /var/www/html/bar
```

I raised the log level of mod_rewrite and found out it did the match, but Apache was expand matching the local path of `/`, which is `/var/www/html` and using that to redirect the browser, which won't work.

I tried using `[PT]` which I thought would prevent the expansion, but it didn't.

Any idea on how I can prevent that from happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a "conflict" with an earlier directive. `RewriteRule` directives are applied to the results of previous `RewriteRule`s. In what context is this directive being used? Where has the `test` subdirectory gone in the resulting URL: `http://testserver/foo/var/www/html`?

Comment: You have a dot at the end of `RewriteRule.` - I assume that is just a typo in your question?

Comment: Yes, the trailing dot is just a typo.

Comment: @MrWhite you're right, it's also a typo. The resulting URL is something like: **testserver/test/var/www/html** but I'd expect something like: **testserver/test/foo/**. Perhaps you're right, and maybe there's another RewriteRule before, it's strange because it is an stock Ubuntu installation. What puzzles me is that this only happens within an **<If>** block. Moving it outside that blocks and it works just fine.

Comment: I came across a temporal solution which is to use **%{REQUEST_URI}** instead of pattern matching and globing. This works because I need whole request resource path. 

However, the initial question remains, because that solution won't work if a part of the request is needed.

Comment: Using `%{REQUEST_URI}` is a good alternative. In fact, this is sometimes preferred (it avoids a backreference and works the same regardless of context, ie. server or directory context). Add your entire rule block (`<If>` wrapper) to your question, so we can have a look - maybe if you're capturing a subpattern in the expression this is being passed through to mod_rewrite? Also, what _context_ are these directives being used... Directly in the server config? Virtual host? Directory wrapper? Or `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to @MrWhite, I'm attaching the relevant `<if>` block:

```
<If "env('var1') =='1' && env('var2') =='0' && env('var3') =='1'"  >
           Define                  requestUri              $1
           Define                  backend              $customDomain
           RewriteEngine           on
           RewriteCond             %{REQUEST_URI}          !^/redir/.*$
           RewriteRule             ^(.*)$                  /redir/%{REQUEST_URI}
</If>
```

This block is under `<Location>` block, which in turn is under the main `<VirtualHost>` block.

If I move it out of the `<If>` block, the pattern `^(.*)$` gives us the same `%{REQUEST_URI}` would return. Inside the `<If>` block, it expands to the local filesystem + the resource requested (if I request `/index.html` it expands to `/var/www/html/index.html`.

Never mind about those **Define** in the block, they do nothing and have no effect.

Thanks